# Using c++ how to show overlay icon in finder mac osx

Tags: c++, macos, qt, overlay, finder

Recently we developed a MAC installer(.dmg). This is developed in c++ and QT. We had a hard requirement to show overlay icons on the files in the finder like how CVS/Dropbox shows sync status on files.

My question is exactly similar to below post. I understand that, if we try to show overlay icons in finder, MAC app store doesn't allow my app to be there. I am fine with this, my users will download the app from the website.

[How can i add icon overlay in finder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7991131/how-can-i-add-icon-overlay-in-finder)

Am pretty much new to MAC and c++ also, Can you please provide me suggestion or solution in c++ in detailed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can i add icon overlay in finder?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7991131/how-can-i-add-icon-overlay-in-finder)

Answer (score 2):

I know this answer is somewhat late, but better than no answer, isn't it?!

Dropbox uses an open source framework called [mach_inject](https://github.com/rentzsch/mach_inject). Originally developed by Jonathan Rentzsch, and known as Mach_Star, it allows code injection into applications.

Dropbox use this to inject into the OSX Finder application. If you Google for "Dropbox mach_inject" you'll find various references to this. Although it's not exactly what you want, there's also a project [here](https://github.com/infinitelabs/FinderMenu/) which also injects into Finder, but to add menu items. You should be able to use that as reference.